# How to get current page url in static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, url, static-block

I want to get my current page URL in one of my static blocks

How do I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me

Add the following code in your static blocks
suppose my page is `abc.html`, then add

```
{{store url="abc.html"}}
```

And if it is a category, then add

```
{{store url="Your category name"}}
```

It worked for me. You can also try

Thanks